# Drawing a figure from an array of coordinates with C and SDL

Tags: c, sdl

I am trying to draw a figure in C, and I have succeded in doing that, but I'm wondering if the way I'm doing it is making it hard for me to what I want to do next (making the figure move/bounce).

I have made a `for` loop in main that iterates through an array of coordinates which then again call a function that draws lines between them and fills it with color. What I'm wondering about is if this `for` loop is the best way to do this?

I have made this for loop in main:

```
for(i = 0; i < SPHERE_NUMTRIANGLES; i++){
                    object = CreateObject(screen,&sphere_model[i],SPHERE_NUMTRIANGLES);
                    object->model->scale = 0.1f;
                    DrawObject(object);
                }
```

The sphere_model im trying to draw contains of many coordinates on the form:

```
  #define SPHERE_NUMTRIANGLES    478
triangle_t sphere_model[] = {
{
.x1=-1,
.y1=-500,
.x2=-1,
.y2=-489,
.x3=-1,
.y3=-500,
.fillcolor=0xeeeeee,
.scale=1.0
},
```

The CreateObject gets the model from the for loop

```
// Create new object
object_t *CreateObject(SDL_Surface *screen, triangle_t *model, int numtriangles)
{
        object_t *object;

        object = NULL;

        object = malloc(sizeof(object_t));
        object->model = malloc(sizeof(triangle_t) * numtriangles);
        object->screen = screen;
        object->ttl;
        object->speedx = 0;
        object->speedy = 1;
        object->model = model;
        object->model->scale;
        object->model->tx = 100;
        object->model->ty = 100;
        return object;
}
```

and finally the DrawObject just calls a function that draws the triangles

```
void DrawObject(object_t *object)
{
    DrawTriangle(object->screen,object->model);

}
```

The `sphere_model` is in `sphere_data.h` and the `CreateObject` function is in `triangle.c`

I'm supposed to create multiple figures and add the created figures to a list after this, but I'm currently trying to just make one. (This is homework, but I'm hoping I can get some help here, I'm struggling a bit)

Comment: It would be better to put all the relevant code needed to compile the program into the question. The link may die making this useless for future reference or some users may not be able to download the tarball easily. Please put enough code into the question to make a minimal, compilable, runnable example program.

Comment: Ok, i have now put in the code i think is needed, i hope its enough

Comment: Yeah, that looks like one can understand what you are doing now. Much better.

Answer (score 0):

> ...hard for me to what I want to do next (making the figure move/bounce).

What i see is that you allocate objects, draw them and then forget them (I do not see you deallocate the memory). Then, if you want to draw the model again at a different place, you will have to go through the loop again, creating objects, drawing them (and forgetting them).

Maybe it would be better to remember the objects created so you can later just change their coordinates before redrawing them. As an example:

```
typedef struct LIST {
    struct LIST *next;
    object_t *object;
};
struct LIST *pObjectList, *pList;

// create objects, draw them and save in list
pObjectList= pList= calloc(1,sizeof(struct LIST));

for(i = 0; i < SPHERE_NUMTRIANGLES; i++){
    object = CreateObject(screen,&sphere_model[i],SPHERE_NUMTRIANGLES);
    object->model->scale = 0.1f;
    DrawObject(object);
    pList->object= object;
    pList= pList->next= calloc(1,sizeof(struct LIST));
}
// offset the model with 50 pixels
pList= pObjectList;
while (pList->object) {
    pList->object.x1 += 50; pList->object.y1 += 50;
    pList->object.x2 += 50; pList->object.y2 += 50;
    pList->object.x3 += 50; pList->object.y3 += 50;
    pList= pList->next;
}
// redraw
pList= pObjectList;
for(i = 0; i < SPHERE_NUMTRIANGLES; i++, pList= pList->next)
{
    DrawObject(pList->object);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.